# Angular input event is not fired by setting the value with the model

Tags: angular, typescript, events, input, ngmodel

I use a input field which calls a method when the value in it changes. But when I set the value in the input field by the `ngModel` (not typed by hand) the "value changed" event of the input field will not be fired.

Input field:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="orderNumberFilter" (input)="updateOrderNumberFilter($event)" [(ngModel)]="orderNumberFilterValue">
</div>
```

component:

```
public updateData(evt: any): void {
  .finally(() => {
    this.orderNumberFilterValue = "test"
  })
  .subscribe(
    //get data from backend
  });
}


public updateOrderNumberFilter(evt: any): void {

 //do stuff with the event

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And it will not be fired, because `input` event will be fired only during user interaction.

You can work with `Reactive Forms` instead of `Template Driven Forms` and using its `valueChanges` function you can listen to changes of the value of the controls.

Another answer about *Reactive Form value changes* you can read [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179389/subscribe-to-valuechanges-from-input-formcontrol-in-formgroup)

**UPDATED**

You can declare your function to get the `value` of the input

```
public updateOrderNumberFilter(value: any): void {

}
```

In the markup attach it with `$event.target.value`

```
<input type="text" id="orderNumberFilter" (input)="updateOrderNumberFilter($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="orderNumberFilterValue">
```

and also call it in the `finally` and pass the `value`.

Comment: Is it possible to send the event programmatically? So I could call the updateOrderNumberFilter method from the finally?

Comment: You just need to access the value ? What you want to do with `evt` parameter ?

Comment: I need the value in that method to evaluate it and pass it to the ag-grid framework

Answer (score 1):

So you can call the `updateData` method manually from the place where you update the model (`orderNumberFilterValue`)