# Subscribing to input type file changes with FormControl?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, html5-filesystem

When I subscribe to a `FormControl.valueChanges()` that is triggered by the selection of a file on an `input` the value emitted does not contain the full path to the file that was selected.  Is it possible to obtain this information via subscription or do we have to pull it off of the element directly with `@ViewChild` to get direct access to the element?  The setup looks like this:

```
<input #file name='file' id='file' type='file' [formControl]='loadButton'/>
```

It's subscribed to like this:

```
this.loadButton.valueChanges
    .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
    .subscribe(path => {
      console.dir(path);
    });
}
```

When a file is selected the logged statement looks like this:

```
C:\fakepath\test.png
```

Comment: Have you looked to [subscribe to valueChanges from input FormControl in FormGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179389/subscribe-to-valuechanges-from-input-formcontrol-in-formgroup) ?

Comment: @HDJEMAI yes.  That is for normal input fields that contains strings like first name last name, etc.  This is for a file, so the semantics are slightly different.

Comment: Made it a feature request: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my project, I did it in one component, like:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-uploader',
  template: '<input type="file" (change)="onUploadFileChanged($event)" />',
})
export class ImageUploaderComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() uploadStatusChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
    onUploadFileChanged(event) {
        this.targetElement = event.target;
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            component.uploadStatusChange.emit('ready');
        }
    }

}
```

Now, after selected file, the component will told parent component I'm ready, then you can set fromControl patch it to true. The HTML of parent component like, for above exmaple, the $event equal string 'ready':

```
<app-image-uploader (uploadStatusChange)="yourFunction($event)"></app-image-uploader>
```

For image, you also can use FileReader show it before upload.